# Regular Lua interpreter vs LuaJIT interpreter?

Tags: lua, interpreter, luajit

So, I was just wondering if there are any advantages of using the normal Lua interpreter instead of the LuaJIT interpreter for anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- PUC Lua (the "normal interpreter") is more stable, i.e. bugs are more frequently found in LuaJIT.
- PUC Lua is smaller, i.e. it takes less memory.
- PUC Lua is much easier to understand if you want to customize it.
- PUC Lua has been ported to way more platforms and is easier to port.
- Like @lhf said, LuaJIT does not support all of Lua 5.2 features yet.

Answer (score 4):

LuaJIT is excellent software, amazing even, but it only supports Lua 5.1, not Lua 5.2. It does support many features of Lua 5.2 as [extensions](http://luajit.org/extensions.html).
So, depending on what features of Lua 5.2 that you need, you may need to use the Lua interpreter from lua.org.